# Не получается сделать шапку сайта(html css).Не могу расставить элементы в шапке

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Всем доброго времени суток! Помогите пожалуйста сделать шапку [сайта](https://www.figma.com/file/BL7wdCOSIxYFu1uxctuVzg/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-Pied-Piper?node-id=0%3A1)(макет в Figma).Брать левый вариант. Надо использовать позиционирование relative. Сама проблема: у меня не получается расположить элементы шапки так, как в макете. Я новичок в frontend, поэтому прошу вас скинуть код и объяснение к нему. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Здесь вам никто с нуля код писать не будет, разместите свою попытку и мы скажем, что вам лучше сделать.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Но у меня  вообще плохо получается. И если править мой код, то  новый код. отнюдь будет не похож на старый Потому, что у меня нет идей и я ни разу не писал такие проекты.Шапка состоит из двух элементов. и если вы хорошо разбираетесь, то за 10 минут сможете написать код и объяснить

Comment: Я икал инфу в инете и пытался разобраться сам. Но все тщетно. Поэтому и жду ответа от профессионала

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не вижу смысла использовать тут `position: relative` 
Объясню как сделал я. 
Сразу скажу что я использовал обнуляющие стили
Коротко об этом [Cовременный сброс](https://webformyself.com/sovremennyj-sbros-css/) 
На макете мы видим, что в шапке элементы выстроены в таком типо контейнере, но в то же время заливка в шапке должна быть до краёв экрана (каким бы экран не был), значит внутри header и контейнер с блоками

```html
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- тут будет разметка шапки -->
        </div>
    </header>
```

Далее для удобства будет использовать список ul 
*То что справа элементы это я предполагаю будут ссылки, поэтому вставляем его в li* 
**Также добавим первому элементу шапки(наше лого) класс .logo, опять же для удобства*

```html
<ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu_item logo">
                    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
                </li>
                <li class="menu_item">
                    <a href="#">the problem</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu_item">
                    <a href="#">PiedPiperCoin</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu_item">
                    <a href="#">the team</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Когда разметка завершена приступаем к стилям.
Из figma можно высчитать ширину всего контейнера, она 1110 пикселей, сделаем контейнер с такой шириной 
Укажем контейнеру что все блоки будут по центру (свойство margin)

```css
.container 
{
    width: 1110px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Высота всей шапки 84px, устанавливаем фон

```css
.header
{
    background-color: #007765;
    height: 84px;
}
```

Т.к. все элементы находятся ровно по центру шапки(вертикаль), то чтобы не морочиться с margin'ами используем свойство `display: flex` и `align-items: center` *(второе без первого работать не будет)*
 Также указываем родителю списка (ul.menu) что его высота будет такая же как высота header (84px), это нужно для того чтобы выравнивание по вертикали было ровным.

```css
ul.menu
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 84px;
}
```

Скажем нашему лого чтобы все элементы отступили от него на 502 пикселя (согласно отступу из figma)

```css
.menu_item.logo
{
    margin-right: 502px;
}
```

Теперь, когда все элементы выстроены, займёмся стилизацией правой части

```css
.menu_item a
{
    font-size: 24px; /*Согласно figma размер шрифта 24px*/
    color: #fff;  
    text-decoration: none; /*Отменяем стандартную стилизацию ссылок, их подчёркивание*/
    padding-right: 10px;  /*Справа и слева делаем отступ по 10px*/
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff; /*Справа делаем что-то типо разделителя*/
}

ul.menu .menu_item:last-child a
{
    border: none; /*У последнего элемента отменяем разделитель (его нет в макете)*/
}
```

Добавляем анимацию при наводке

```css
.menu_item:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ. Я разобрался.